# Kasus nach „plus” and „minus” und „±“ . Which case should go after „plus”, „minus” and „±“?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

I wanted to write

> 1 Monat ± 1 Tag

in German (which still isn't). Then I noticed I didn't even know how to write this with `+` or `-`. It seems, or I feel, like I need to decline *ein Tag*.

Indeed [minus is a preposition](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/minus#Pr.C3.A4position) which accepts everything as case (except the boring nominative, which nobody expected):

> **minus** *Präposition mit Dativ, Akkusativ oder Genitiv*: vermindert um, verringert um

- So, should I assume *plus* obeys the same rule?
- Finally, would you have objections if I go with dative for *plus/minus*? This being the right case, just for completeness, I would write

> Ein Monat plus/minus **einem** Tag wäre die Dauer. (?)

Comment: That is fine. If Duden indicates dative first you may assume that the dative is the most frequent case. I have not heard plus/minus + genitive.

Comment: "...besteht aus 6 Spieler plus einem Torwart" – "Das Team stellt 6 Spieler plus einen Torwart" – "6 Spieler plus ein Torwart machen ein Team" – Mir fällt jetzt nichts mit Genitiv ein, und bin zu faul zum Googlen.

Comment: "Ich würde einen Monat plus minus **einen** Tag da bleiben". – "Nach einem Monat plus minus einem Tag solltest du abreisen."

Comment: Intuitiv hätte ich jetzt gesagt, dass es "...besteht aus sechs Feldspielern plus *einem* Torwart" heißt, weil "aus" den Dativ verlangt. Deshalb würde ich in deinem letzten Satz "...plus minus einen Tag" verwenden, weil "bleiben" ja auch "einen Monat" im Akkusativ verlangt.

Comment: @Em1: "... besteht aus 6 Spieler*n* plus einem Torwart" - Mehrzahl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly suspect that it depends on the case that the entire sum or difference would be put in:

> ... besteht aus sechs Feldspielern *(Dativ)* plus einem Torwart.
>
> Ich würde einen Monat *(Akkusativ)* plus minus einen Tag da bleiben.
>
> Elf Monate plus ein Monat *(Nominativ)* ergeben ein Jahr.

[*Plus* and *minus* generally permit any case.](https://books.google.de/books?id=iW-9BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA613&lpg=PA613&dq=grammatischer+kasus+nach+plus+minus&source=bl&ots=sewd75GqKN&sig=9njGx3fOf3LM43N4Abxup6GR6sc&hl=de&sa=X&ei=Dl7vVMGSJ4GqOvbEgSA&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=grammatischer%20kasus%20nach%20plus%20minus&f=false)

Comment: You mean, plus and minus are subordinate to the other prepepositions bzw. other cases induced by whatever situation?

Comment: @c.p. Yes, since plus (and hence minus and plus/minus) is not much more than a synonym for und, which implies "besteht aus sechs Feldspielern und einem Torwart". "besteht aus sechs Feldspielern und ein/eines/einen Torwart" are wrong.

Answer (score 7):

According to Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch,* both *plus* and *minus* can be followed by all four cases.

The word *plus* can be a preposition (the preposition with genitive particularly appears in business parlance and may be replaced by „zuzüglich“)

> das Gehalt plus den üblichen Zulagen *(recommended)*; das Gehalt plus der üblichen Zulagen
>   das Gehalt plus Einkünften aus Nebentätigkeiten
>   für das Gehalt plus üblichem Zuschlag *(recommended)*; für das Gehalt plus üblichen Zuschlags
>   mit dem Gehalt plus übliche Zulagen *(recommended)*; mit dem Gehalt plus üblicher Zulagen

or a conjunction (which may be replaced by „und“ or  „sowie“ )

> das Gehalt plus die üblichen Zulagen
>   das Gehalt plus Einkünfte aus Nebentätigkeiten
>   für das Gehalt plus üblichen Zuschlag
>   mit dem Gehalt plus üblichen Zulagen

Isolated, strong-inflected singular nouns stay without inflectional suffix:

> der Betrag plus Porto
>   der Betrag minus Rabatt

According to Duden, the expression for ‘±’ is „plus/minus“:

> mit einer Genauigkeit von plus/minus 5 Prozent
>   wir kamen mit plus/minus null aus der Sache heraus